# Nature of inequalities near origin

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality

What can be said about these statements if point $(x,y)$ is sufficiently close to origin $(0,0)$.

$$x+y+4 \sin x \sin y \ge0$$
$$2x^2 + 3y^2 +4 \sin x \sin y\ge 0$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close to the origin,
$$\sin x = x +O(x^3)$$

Hence as $x,y\to 0$ your first statement is equivalent to
$$x +y +4xy +O(x^3) + O(y^3) \ge 0$$ 
This is not true in general.

Your second statement is equivalent to
$$2x^2 + 3y^2 +4xy +O(x^3) + O(y^3) \ge 0$$
and this is true in general because
$$2x^2 + 3y^2 +4xy = 2(x+y)^2 + y^2$$

---

It's also possible to show this using Taylor series approximations

In the first case 
$$\begin{align}
f_x &= 1 + 4\cos x \sin y\\
f_x(0,0) &= 1\\
f_y &= 1 + 4\sin x \cos y\\
f_y(0,0) &= 1\\
f(x,y) &\approx f(0,0) + xf_x(0,0) + yf_y(0,0) &\mbox{near the origin}\\
&= x + y
\end{align}$$

Clearly this can be $<0$.

The second case has $f_x(0,0)=f_y(0,0)=0$ so you need the second derivatives (in other words, it's a stationary point)
$$\begin{align}
f_x &= 4x + 4\cos x \sin y\\
f_x(0,0) &= 0\\
f_y &= 6y + 4\sin x \cos y\\
f_y(0,0) &= 0\\
f_{xx} &= 4 - 4\sin x\sin y\\
f_{xx}(0,0) &= 4\\
f_{yy} &= 6 - 4\sin x \sin y\\
f_{yy}(0,0) &= 6\\
f_{xy} &= 4\cos x \cos y\\
f_{xy}(0,0) &= 4\\
f(x,y) &\approx f(0,0) + xf_x(0,0) + yf_y(0,0) +\\
&\;\;\;(x^2f_{xx}(0,0) + 2xyf_{xy}(0,0) + y^2f_{yy}(0,0))/2 &\mbox{near the origin}\\
&= 2x^2 + 3y^2 + 4xy
\end{align}$$

For the reasons already given this is $\ge 0$. Equivalently, construct the Hessian matrix.

---

Finally, it's easy to plot these functions to see if the plots are consistent with the analysis

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can this be explained with hessian matrix or by other means?

Comment: Possibly something like that. That's why I commented that perhaps the calculus tag should be there as well. Hessian is second derivatives (and need firstderivatives to be zero to be useful). Here your functions are zero at origin so you could expand using Taylor series / first derivatives. Sorry I'm out tonight so don't have pen and paper to try it out.  Think my way  probably easier.

Comment: Yeah I have problem understanding this with hessian/calculus approach. Your way definitely works too!

Comment: @ELEC I've updated my answer to include the calculus-based analysis. It's intructive, at least insofar as it shows it's a lot more work. In the second case I've simply extended the Taylor series out to the second derivatives. This is equivalent to the "Hessian matrix" approach, which you can easily verify.

Comment: Thank you really much for the effort! You are good at teaching! :)